# PostgreSQL 9.4 не использует индекс, если не указан ORDER BY

Tags: postgresql

Такая ситуация. Используется PostgreSQL 9.4.
Есть таблица messages_conversation, в которой есть индексы:

```
CREATE INDEX messages_conversation_multi_index ON messages_conversation 
USING btree (app_id, replied, closed, assignee_id, tags) 
WHERE replied = TRUE

CREATE INDEX messages_conversation_last_update_f0131d4a8e80d76_uniq
ON messages_conversation USING btree (last_update)

CREATE INDEX messages_conversation_f382adfe
ON messages_conversation USING btree (app_id)
```

И есть 2 запроса к этой таблице:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT "messages_conversation"."id", "messages_conversation"."created", "messages_conversation"."last_update", "messages_conversation"."user_id", "messages_conversation"."app_id", "messages_conversation"."read", "messages_conversation"."replied", "messages_conversation"."clicked", "messages_conversation"."unsubscribed", "messages_conversation"."bounced", "messages_conversation"."spam", "messages_conversation"."goal_completed", "messages_conversation"."goal_profit", "messages_conversation"."external_service", "messages_conversation"."external_id", "messages_conversation"."settings", "messages_conversation"."replies_count", "messages_conversation"."parts_count", "messages_conversation"."part_last_id", "messages_conversation"."reply_last_id", "messages_conversation"."reply_last_type", "messages_conversation"."user_unread_count", "messages_conversation"."last_django_user_id", "messages_conversation"."tags", "messages_conversation"."closed", "messages_conversation"."message_id", "messages_conversation"."assignee_id", "messages_conversation"."type", "messages_conversation"."reply_type" 
FROM "messages_conversation" 
WHERE ("messages_conversation"."app_id" = 5038 
    AND "messages_conversation"."replied" = true 
    AND "messages_conversation"."closed" = false) 
ORDER BY "messages_conversation"."last_update" DESC, replied DESC 
LIMIT 20;

QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=7569.71..7569.76 rows=20 width=169) (actual time=0.363..0.366 rows=12 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=7569.71..7749.36 rows=71860 width=169) (actual time=0.360..0.362 rows=12 loops=1)
         Sort Key: last_update, replied
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
         ->  Index Scan using messages_conversation_multi_index on messages_conversation  (cost=0.43..5657.54 rows=71860 width=169) (actual time=0.030..0.336 rows=12 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((app_id = 5038) AND (replied = true) AND (closed = false))
               Filter: (NOT closed)
 Planning time: 0.150 ms
 Execution time: 0.403 ms
(9 rows)
```

И второй:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "messages_conversation"."id", "messages_conversation"."created", "messages_conversation"."last_update", "messages_conversation"."user_id", "messages_conversation"."app_id", "messages_conversation"."read", "messages_conversation"."replied", "messages_conversation"."clicked", "messages_conversation"."unsubscribed", "messages_conversation"."bounced", "messages_conversation"."spam", "messages_conversation"."goal_completed", "messages_conversation"."goal_profit", "messages_conversation"."external_service", "messages_conversation"."external_id", "messages_conversation"."settings", "messages_conversation"."replies_count", "messages_conversation"."parts_count", "messages_conversation"."part_last_id", "messages_conversation"."reply_last_id", "messages_conversation"."reply_last_type", "messages_conversation"."user_unread_count", "messages_conversation"."last_django_user_id", "messages_conversation"."tags", "messages_conversation"."closed", "messages_conversation"."message_id", "messages_conversation"."assignee_id", "messages_conversation"."type", "messages_conversation"."reply_type" 
FROM "messages_conversation" 
WHERE ("messages_conversation"."app_id" = 5038 
    AND "messages_conversation"."replied" = true 
    AND "messages_conversation"."closed" = false) 
ORDER BY "messages_conversation"."last_update" DESC 
LIMIT 20;

QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Limit  (cost=0.56..985.38 rows=20 width=169) (actual time=0.045..108297.855 rows=7 loops=1)
    ->  Index Scan Backward using messages_conversation_last_update_f0131d4a8e80d76_uniq on messages_conversation  (cost=0.56..3538428.71 rows=71860 width=169) (actual time=0.045..108297.849 rows=7 loops=1)
        Filter: (replied AND (NOT closed) AND (app_id = 5038))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 56438067
Planning time: 0.149 ms
Execution time: 108297.886 ms
(6 rows)
```

Как видно из запросов, единственное отличие - ORDER BY replied DESC. Это boolean, для которого в WHERE жестко стоит replied=true. Все поля where подпадают под индекс выше.

А теперь, внимание вопрос: Почему во 2 случае не был применен Index Cond, хотя поля WHERE не изменились? Почему вообще удаление сортировки повлияло на внутреннее условие?

Ну и не совсем понял: зачем в 1 запросе Filter: (NOT closed), если он есть в индексе?

Comment: На вопросы "почему план именно такой" точно вам никто не ответит кроме разработчиков оптимизатора postrgesql. Все остальные могут только гадать какая логика была применена. Для выбора конкретного индекса и пути выполнения оптимизатор руководствуется большим объемом дополнительной информации, которую из строения таблицы и планов выполнения не видно. Например статистикой по количеству тех или иных значений в колонках. Он вычисляет стоимость для разных путей и выбирает тот что считает лучше.

Comment: На самом деле, вопрос не в том, почему так построен индекс, а как убрать лишнюю сортировку не потеряв индекс? И как заставить оптимизатор им пользоваться без костыльной сортировки?